# Nuget List command is not including all results from Artifactory Nuget repository

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I have a PS script that pulls the latest build for a specific product version from Nuget using nuget list. However, one product does not seem to be showing all builds in the results. I have the repository mirrored to another server and the mirror server works correctly.

For instance, running `.\nuget list productName -Prerelease -AllVersions -ConfigFile .\nuget.config -Source MyServer` returns 351 results on the main server but 483 on the mirror server. I put these results into Excel and found that certain versions only return the first build alphabetically.

In the list below, only the first item in the list is returned by `nuget list`

```
Product 3.0.9-rc.3
Product 3.0.9-rc.30
Product 3.0.9-rc.4
Product 3.0.9-rc.5
```

We have had this happen one other time and it seemed to resolve itself by reindexing the repository but that is not working this time. I also rebooted the server with no effect.

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
Artifactory: 4.3.2
Database: MSSQL